# How can I install torch and torchvision with pip and python 3.8.3 on windows in an virtual environment?

Tags: pip, pytorch

I created a virtual environment for my project and I'm trying to install `torch` via `pip`.

```
pip install torch===1.5.1 torchvision===0.6.1 -f https://download.pytorch.org/whl/torch_stable.html
```

This gives me the error -

```
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement torch===1.5.1 (from versions: 0.1.2, 0.1.2.post1, 0.1.2.post2)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for torch===1.5.1
```

Some solutions recommend the use of conda, is it necessary? Can I not do it through just `pip`

Comment: what happens when you just use `pip install torch torchvision` ? as 1.5.1 is the latest stable version.

Comment: `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tools.nnwrap` I got this error.

Comment: Did you solve this issue already?

Answer (score 0):

You can try to install directly from the wheels files:

```
pip install https://download.pytorch.org/whl/cu102/torch-1.5.1-cp36-cp36m-win_amd64.whl
pip install https://download.pytorch.org/whl/cu102/torchvision-0.6.1-cp36-cp36m-win_amd64.whl
```

Comment: I get this error -
`ERROR: torch-1.5.1-cp36-cp36m-win_amd64.whl is not a supported wheel on this platform.`

Comment: you have to change the 36 with your python version, and `win` with your platform

Comment: so if i am 3.8, i should make it 38? i am already on windows, so `win` is correct right?

Comment: try with 37, as I think that is the highest python version they have

Comment: The easiest solution for you would be to create another environment with python 3.6 or 3.7, or use conda